# C# Entity Framework cast my type into DateTime

Tags: c#, date, datetime, entity-framework-core

UPDATE
That was the solution:

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        configurationBuilder.Properties<Date>()
            .HaveConversion<DateConverter>()
            .HaveColumnType("date");
    }
```

---

---

---

I have my own Date type.
Exactly it is a wrapper class for DateOnly type the difference is this three lines:

```
public static implicit operator Date(DateTime dateTime) => ConvertFromDateTime(dateTime);
public static implicit operator Date(DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset) => ConvertFromDateTimeOffset(dateTimeOffset.Date);
public static implicit operator DateTime(Date date) => date.ConvertToDateTime();
```

I have a converter and comparer class

```
internal class DateConverter : ValueConverter<Date, DateTime>
{
    public DateConverter() : base(
        date => date,
        dateTime => dateTime)
    {
    }
}


internal class DateComparer : ValueComparer<Date>
{
    public DateComparer() : base(
        (d1, d2) => d1 == d2,
        d => d.GetHashCode())
    {
    }
}
```

So i can save and read from Database.

My problem is if i use a LinQ expression, the comparers not work right.
Forexample:

```
 DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2023, 04, 03, 12, 0, 0);
        DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime);
        Date date = Date.ConvertFromDateTime(dateTime);

 var something_date_check = await Something
            .Where(s => s.Deadline > date)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        var something_datetime_check = await Something
            .Where(s => s.Deadline > dateTime)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        var something_datetimeoffset_check = await Something
            .Where(s => s.Deadline > dateTimeOffset)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Where Deadline type is my own Date type.
I noticed my date type comparers are never runs.
I think EF cast my Date into DateTime and it is generate false results.

Comment: You can't add SQL support for a custom type with a `ValueConverter`. That class only tells EF Core how to transform one value into another. It doesn't tell EF how to generate SQL for that type, what operators or functions are supported. Not even how to represent a static value of your custom type in SQL. A Value Comparer on the other hand has nothing to do with the database. It's [used to detect changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers), not generate SQL

Comment: Why don't you use `DateOnly`? What database are you targeting? Which EF Core version?

Comment: Because i need cast operators...

Comment: That doesn't answer why you want to use your custom client-side types in the ORM entities. EF and any ORM needs to be told how to map a custom type, how to generate SQL statements for it, how to emit values.  That's a complex job done by database providers, not application code. You can create custom conversion functions. You can use AutoMapper to map the database types to your own custom types.

Comment: If you really want to add your own custom types you should tell EF Core about your types *and* provide mappings for the databases you want to use. You can check the files needed to add `DateOnly` support in EF Core [in Github](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Fefcore+dateonly&type=code&p=1). A crude search for `EF Core` returns 48 files, about half of them tests. Some of them add type and value support to EF Core itself, some add translation support to SQLite, some to SQL Server. You'll have to do the same for your `Date` class.